# How to set the path of the swiftmailer templates

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

What I tried is `'viewPath' => '@frontend/views/mail'`. It is still search for the `layouts/html` because it is setted to this file. How to override it ? I tried to leave the `htmlLayout` property empty but it searches for `.../frontend/views/mail/.php`. How to disable ( if I can say it like this ) the `htmlLayout` property ? My code look like:

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            'htmlLayout' => '',
            'viewPath' => '@frontend/views/mail',
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'username' => Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'],
                'password' => Yii::$app->params['adminEmailPass'],
                'port' => '587',
                'encryption' => 'tls',
            ],
        ],
```

Sending the mail like:

```
Yii::$app->mailer->compose('contact',[
                'title' => 'test'
            ])
            ->setFrom(Yii::$app->params['adminEmail'])
            ->setTo($model->email)
            ->setSubject(Yii::t('app', 'Successfully sent message')." - ".Yii::$app->name)
            ->send();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in [documentation](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/2.0.15.1/framework/mail/BaseMailer.php#L51) - set it to `false`.